# Managing modules - site overriding

Tags: 7

I have drupal site, where modules are centrally managed. In case I want to have different version of module I put it to sites/my-site-name/modules/moduleX.. but now I want to go back to the centrally managed version..

I cannot turn it off as it's in dependency with field and some other modules. If I just delete it, site runs with error which prevents me from clearing cache (which would start using the central version of module again). I could change it via myPhpAdmin by chaning records in table 'system', but after changing them to old path (/sites/all/modules/moduleX) it doesn't look for the new file - I guess there's a need for cache clear..

seems stupid and easy but cannot figure it out. any ideas?

---

edit: maybe just deleting everything from "cache_bootstrap" table will do?

Answer (score 1):

Clearing caches should definitely do the trick. You can manually truncate each of the tables whose name begins with `cache_`, or (far preferably) you can install [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).

The Drush command to clear caches is simply:

```
drush cc all
```

Comment: As I said - Drupal is centrally managed, drush is not an option - i was thinking about it. truncation of cache_bootstrap and some other one didn't help. i will try to empty all of cache_* tables.

Comment: doesn't work. I dumped whole DB and replaced all occurences of "sites/my-site/moduleX" to "sites/all/moduleX" and deleted the module folder, but it still comes back with that message.. i keep deleting records in "sessions" and "cache" and "watchdogs" but it doesn't help.

Comment: Then your question is faulty. You say "As I said" about not being able to use Drush, yet you haven't mentioned Drush once in the question. Drush is the correct way to handle this; if your setup won't support Drush, then there's something wrong with your setup. You need to analyse your current methodologies to identify what the problems are, and adjust your workflow accordingly.

Comment: IMO, Saying "centrally managed drupal instalation" (where I only have access to files of one site in folder /sites) implicates not having tools like Drush which requires console/ssh.